# Combining groupby() and qcut() - "could not convert string to float"

Tags: python, pandas

This is my dataframe, ~5000 entries in total:

```
data.head(3)

    filename    date        var1    var2    age     sex
0   file1.jpg   2012-01-17  132.32  199.17  31.0    2.0
1   file2.jpg   2012-01-17  134.88  196.50  31.0    2.0
2   file3.jpg   2012-01-17  151.19  209.07  31.0    2.0
3   ...
```

I want to divide this dataset into 10 quantile groups based on `var1`. No problem:

```
data['var1_groups'] = pd.qcut(data['var1'], 10)
data.head(3)

    filename    date        var1    var2    age     sex   var1_groups
0   file1.jpg   2012-01-17  132.32  199.17  31.0    2.0   (129.488, 133.659]
1   file2.jpg   2012-01-17  134.88  196.50  31.0    2.0   (133.659, 138.176]
2   file3.jpg   2012-01-17  151.19  209.07  31.0    2.0   (148.196, 153.09]
3   ...
```

Now, within the `var1` groups, I want a further subdivision in `age` quantile groups.
So I try this:

```
data['age_groups'] = data.groupby(['var1_groups'])['age'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 3))

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-164-998f598868ed> in <module>()
----> 1 data['age_groups'] = data.groupby(['var1_groups'])['age'].transform(lambda x: pd.qcut(x, 3))

/usr/lib/miniconda3/envs/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in transform(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
   2762 
   2763             indexer = self._get_index(name)
-> 2764             result[indexer] = res
   2765 
   2766         result = _possibly_downcast_to_dtype(result, dtype)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '(53, 69]'
```

What's happening here? Does Pandas try to convert the result category back to the original column's dtype, or something else?

Comment: @sabbahillel, http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.qcut.html

Comment: `Categories (4, object): [[0, 1] < (1, 2] < (2, 3] < (3, 4]]`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks. I guess I need to have my eyes checked. (:-)